# Get content from specific HTML tags with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to find some regex that matches the following 2 html tags and retrieves X and Y from them in 2 seperate groups. X and Y can be any integer from 0-99999.

```
<td align="right">X</td>
<td align="right">Y</td>
```

These are the only 2 tags on the page with td align="right" and I'd appreciate any help at all.

**EDIT**

I'm downloading the following page: http://thebootlegbay.com/search/ubuntu/0/7/0

to download the page I'm using webclient.downloadstring

I would like to capture the ***SEEDERS*** and ***LEACHERS*** of each row in the table with Regex, which are enclosed in the above tags with variable integers inbetween the tags.

It'd be ideal if I could capture the first rows seeders in match group 1, and leachers in match group 2, which would allow me to iterate through the rows in my code and grab the seeders and leachers from each row.. Hope that explains everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/707111

Comment: @false This is a one time use application that will be reading a specific file in which The HTML will never change. It would over complicate the application if I tried to parse it. Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to extract the values inside `<td>` tags.,

```
(?<=td align=\"right\">)([^<]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH9dP8)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to modify it so that it grabs the first 2 occurrences in 2 groups, and then the next match will be the next 2 occurrences. Is this possible with regex or am I approaching the wrong way? I've been reading about multiline modifier so it sounds plausible.

Comment: please provide an example. I'll help you.

Comment: How seeders and leachers looklike. I think you need a `s` modifier.